# Is there any way to print following pattern without using nested loops?

Tags: c++, string

This image contains a pattern. The '*' is getting subtracted and '-' being added.

[image]

Where I am confused that I am not allowed to use nested loop. I don't know why it confused me.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string a="*";
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
        cout<<a<<endl;
        a=a+"*";
    }
}
```

I tried this code to test to print the pattern which successfully it did. Following was the pattern made by it.

```
*
**
***
****
```

This seems fine because C++ allowed `a=a+"*"` which was addition of string into string data. But the pattern I require is

```
****
***-
**--
*---
```

In it, the '-' can be added but how can I subtract '*'. I can't do `a=a-'*'`. Do I need to use indexes of the string? But only one loop is allowed.

Comment: [Please do not post images of texts because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Texts should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: it is a curious use of the design-patterns tag

Comment: `std::cout << "****\n***-\**--\n*---\n----\n";` ^_^.

Comment: Maybe your teacher is expecting you to understand recursion

Comment: @Jarod42 I was also thinking the same to print. Earlier I tried 4 [IF] statements which didn't make any good sense of algorithm so this [COUT] statement was even better than all my previous solutions :-D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change (overwrite) characters in strings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    const int n=4;
    string a(n,'*');
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<a<<endl;
        a[n-i-1]='-';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for answering. Can you please tell me what is **string a(n,'*');** is exactly doing here? n is value 4 and then **a[n-i-1]**. Can I add and subtract strings from a string variable using this method?

Comment: `string a(n, '*')` is an declaration and initialization of `std::string` using [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (2), specifying the number of repeat and the character to repeat.

Comment: You cannot add nor subtract strings via `a[n-i-1]`. It can only read and replace characters. To "subtract" strings, you can use [`substr()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) function,

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i<4;  i++){
    cout << string((4-i), '*') << string(i, '-')<< endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. There was some other solutions like using functions but I was totally restricted by the teacher to use only one for loop and no additional library. I highly appreciate your answer. By looking at your answer, it seems life I need to study String library to play around the strings.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

- Start by making a string of length 4, with just `*`. This uses one loop (or not; that depends whether 4 is always 4, or is variable)
- Make another loop, that counts down from 3 to 0, and replaces that counted character with a `-`. This is another loop, but it is not a nested loop. Output the string for each iteration of the loop, before doing the replacement.

For a `std::string s`, you can use `s[i]='-';` to replace a single character in the string, **if** you know that `i` is within the length of the string.

(Basically what @MikeCAT said)